# SqlCeParameter return Auto ID (Primary Key)

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-4

I have an SQL `SqlCeParameter` statement for example:

```
mySQLCommand1.CommandText = @"
   INSERT INTO clientSubjectiveComplaints (clientSubComplaintCreated)
   VALUES (@ClientSubComplaintCreated)
   ";
```

Once the `INSERT` is successful I need the auto generated ID (INT Primary Key) returned so that I can use it in a second `INSERT` statement.

Is this possible for `SqlCe` ? Please if you can provide an example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this:

```
using (var connection = new SqlCeConnection(Settings.Default.Database1ConnectionString))
using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    connection.Open();

    command.CommandText = @"
        INSERT Test (Name)
        VALUES (@TestName)
        ";
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("TestName", "SomeName");
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    command.CommandText = "SELECT @@IDENTITY";
    var id = command.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Comment: BTW, if you need to get `int id`, the easiest way is to do this: 'var id = Convert.ToInt32((decimal)command.ExecuteScalar());'

Comment: @DevilCode - just curious, what was the judgement, when you selected the answer. I spent time to make working code for you, didn't paste it until made sure it worked. And you selected short answer, that does not even contain valid code statement. On top of that the referenced url does not contain full solution. Also it shows conversion from decimal via string, which is very bad practice. Well... this is something rather discouraging about StackOverflow...

Comment: Hi Alex, This was my bad, it was late at night whenI ticked when i was half asleep. Your answer was great, apologies. I have fixed this now.

Comment: 'var id = Convert.ToInt32((decimal)command.ExecuteScalar());' 
'int id = Convert.ToInt32((decimal)command.ExecuteScalar());'

Answer (score 4):

```
ExecuteScalar("SELECT @@IDENTITY")
```

More details can be found [here](http://czetsuya-tech.blogspot.com/2009/09/sqlce-get-last-insert-id-convert.html).