# Select SCOPE_IDENTITY after insert with SqlCeCommand

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce

My program has an online and offline mode.

- Online it connects to a SQL Server instance using the C# `SqlCommand` classes.
- Offline it connects to a local `.SDF` file using the C# `SqlCeCommand` classes.

Now I want to do the following which works when in online mode

```
GetSqlCommand("insert into my_table (col1) values (@c1); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()", conn))
```

So I insert a record a get back the ID of that new record with `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()`.

But when in offline mode using SQL Server CE, it throws an error. Is there a way to get back ID from the insert with SQL Server CE without running a separate query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server CE doesn't support multiple queries in single command, try as below

```
SqlCeCommand  cmd = new SqlCeCommand("insert into my_table (col1) values (@c1)", conn);
//set paremeter values 
//execute insert 
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
//now change the sql statment to take identity 
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT @@IDENTITY";
int id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6480017/2558060

Answer (score 0):

Although Damith answer is right, Yes We cannot run multiple query with SQL Server CE.

I'm taking the example with same code.

```
    SqlCeCommand  cmd = new SqlCeCommand("insert into my_table (col1) values (@c1)", conn);
    //set paremeter values 
    //execute insert 
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    //now change the sql statment to take identity 
    ////////////////**CONNECTION SHOULD NOT BE CLOSED BETWEEN TWO COMMANDS**/////
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT @@IDENTITY";
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Note: Connection should be open between two commands, otherwise second query will fail.

Better you use this code in Transaction.

Note: SQL Server CE objects are not thread-safe, it may lead to Access Violation exception if instance of `SqlCeConnection` or `SqlCeTransaction` is shared across threads. It is recommended that each thread should use a separate connection, it should not be shared across multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your answer:
[How do I use an INSERT statement's OUTPUT clause to get the identity value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999396/how-do-i-use-an-insert-statements-output-clause-to-get-the-identity-value#10999467) but im not sure about SQL CE.. Give it a try.

**EDIT:**
Then this answer is probably right: [Inserting into SQL Server CE database file and return inserted id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25963314/inserting-into-sql-server-ce-database-file-and-return-inserted-id#25963592)

Comment: Good idea. But sadly CE does not support that: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174633(v=sql.110).aspx